# libtool: error: relink 'libpocketsphinx.la' with the above command before installing it

Tags: error-handling, linker

When I trying to install pocketsphinx by `make install` command`(after ./autogen.sh , ./configure, make commands)` , I get this error message:

```
libtool:  error: relink 'libpocketsphinx.la' with the above command before installing it
```

Comment: try running `make test`

Comment: `make: Nothing to be done for 'test'. `